# What would the best (top) tag hierarchy be?

Tags: discussion, tags

I wanted to share some work I have done to look at the community's tag set and estimate a hierarchy:
[https://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~pmatthew/blog/2020/06/19/a-ux-hierarchy-from-folksonomy/](https://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/%7Epmatthew/blog/2020/06/19/a-ux-hierarchy-from-folksonomy/)

A Vizualisation of top tags is here:
[https://fetstudy.uwe.ac.uk/~pmatthew/ko/ux-tag-viz.html](https://fetstudy.uwe.ac.uk/%7Epmatthew/ko/ux-tag-viz.html)

As you can see, the algorithm has put [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) at the top, though it looks to me like it should instead be [usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability), with [forms](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) and [website-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design) under that.

I'd be really interested in your views, and if you think a hierarchy adds any value

Comment: +1 this is quite an interesting piece of analysis and I think it probably reflects the history and changes of UXSE. I wonder if this work would be useful for helping to suggest tags and provide more useful summaries of activities on UXSE. However, I would suggest that it also reflects the fact that some of our tags are not being used as they probably should because some of the grouping don't seem to follow the conventional hierarchy from a design and UX perspective (e.g. date picker should be grouped with the other input fields), and some abstract concepts at lower places on the hierarchy.